# The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server in odoo

Tags: apache, proxy, xmlhttprequest, odoo, reverse-proxy

While generating the Reports under payroll module in local odoo server - I am getting the following error:

```
Odoo

XmlHttpRequestError Proxy Error

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href="/web/dataset/call_button">POST&nbsp;/web/dataset/call_button</a></em>.<p>
Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.111.188 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when i try to create a new db 
odoo 8.0.17 / bitnami stack

```
> XmlHttpRequestError Proxy Error <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD
> HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>502 Proxy Error</title>
> </head><body> <h1>Proxy Error</h1> <p>The proxy server received an
> invalid response from an upstream server.<br /> The proxy server could
> not handle the request <em><a
> href="/web/database/create">POST&nbsp;/web/database/create</a></em>.<p>
> Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
> </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps to solve the XmlHttpRequestError Proxy Error:

- It is something related to browser end only so use Private Window
- Clear Browser cookie because sometimes cookies are corrupted
- Some times page actually loading but request time out
- It Works For Me try this, you have to update your action module code(for example - model:employee.fine) with empty print statement or something else, now try that action again it works!